# Query rewrite logic

Tags: oracle

I am trying to rewrite the below query as I dont want to use so many window functions . Is there any way to rewrite the below logic . So far I have tried to build temporary tables and using jonins but that didint help much .

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT F.DT_KEY AS DT_KEY
        ,F.COL_KEY AS COL_KEY
        ,F.PCK_ITM_KEY AS PCK_ITM_KEY
        ,F.KEY3 AS KEY3
        ,F.KEY4 AS KEY4
        ,F.KEY1 AS KEY1
        ,F.KEY2 AS KEY2
        ,F.KEY3 AS KEY3
        ,F.SH_QTY AS SH_QTY
        ,SUM(F.SLS_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS SLS_QTY
        ,SUM(F.SLS_RTRN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS SLS_RTRN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.PCHSE_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS PCHSE_QTY
        ,SUM(F.ADJ_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS ADJ_QTY
        ,SUM(F.SED_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS SED_QTY
        ,SUM(F.RTV_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS RTV_QTY
        ,SUM(F.PRN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS PRN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.ML_IN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS ML_IN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.ML_OUT_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS ML_OUT_QTY
        ,SUM(F.BK_ML_IN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS BK_ML_IN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.BK_ML_OUT_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS BK_ML_OUT_QTY
        ,SUM(F.INT_COMP_IN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS INT_COMP_IN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.INT_COMP_OUT_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS INT_COMP_OUT_QTY
        ,SUM(F.ML_RCPT_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS ML_RCPT_QTY
        ,SUM(F.RCPT_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS RCPT_QTY
        ,SUM(F.STCK_ADJ_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS STCK_ADJ_QTY
        ,SUM(F.WHSL_SLS_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS WHSL_SLS_QTY
        ,SUM(F.WH_RTRN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS WH_RTRN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.NET_SLS_AMT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS NET_SLS_AMT
        ,SUM(F.NET_WH_SLS_AMT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS NET_WH_SLS_AMT
        ,F.IN_TRNST_QTY AS IN_TRNST_QTY
        ,F.LST_RCVD_QTY AS LST_RCVD_QTY
        ,F.LST_SLD_QTY AS LST_SLD_QTY
        ,MIN(F.FRST_RCVD_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS FRST_RCVD_DT
        ,MAX(F.LST_RCVD_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS LST_RCVD_DT
        ,MAX(F.LST_LST_RCVD_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS LST_LST_RCVD_DT
        ,MIN(F.FRST_SLD_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS FRST_SLD_DT
        ,MAX(F.LST_SLD_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS LST_SLD_DT
        ,MIN(F.FRST_ML_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS FRST_ML_DT
        ,MAX(F.LST_ML_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY3
            ) AS LST_ML_DT
        ,F.LST_MODFD_DTTM AS LST_MODFD_DTTM
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.KEY4
            ,F.KEY1
            ,F.KEY2
            ,F.KEY3
            ,F.COLE ORDER BY F.DT_KEY DESC
            ) AS RNK
    FROM FCT_ITEM_KEY F
    ) a
WHERE a.RNK = 1;
```

Comment: Is that how **you** work? You look at someone else's code and start changing it, without asking "what does the input data look like", "what is the requirement", and "what should the output like"? If it is, I wouldn't want you working on my code. If not (which is very likely), why do you expect us to work that way? Please show what the inputs are, what the requirement is, and what the output should be. Don't ask us to "guess" by just reading the code - that's not how such things should be done.

Comment: @mathguy I am very new to this forum . Thanks for your suggestion I will include sample data .

Comment: Hi Ciprian, - you might find this useful (when you have time). http://stackoverflow.com/help  And especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use conditional aggregation, if you like:

```
SELECT F.KEY4, F.KEY1, F.KEY2, F.KEY3, F.COLE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN F.DT_KEY END) AS DT_KEY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN F.COL_KEY END) AS COL_KEY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN F.PCK_ITM_KEY END) AS PCK_ITM_KEY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN F.SH_QTY END) AS SH_QTY,
       SUM(F.SLS_QTY) AS SLS_QTY,
       . . . -- similar for all the sums
       MIN(MIN(F.FRST_RCVD_DT)) OVER (PARTITION BY F.KEY1, F.KEY3) AS FRST_RCVD_DT,  -- still need the window function because the keys are a subset of the `group by` keys,
       . . .
FROM (SELECT F.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.KEY4, F.KEY1, F.KEY2, F.KEY3, F.COLE
                                ORDER BY F.DT_KEY DESC
                              ) AS seqnum
      FROM FCT_ITEM_KEY F
     ) F
GROUP BY F.KEY4, F.KEY1, F.KEY2, F.KEY3, F.COLE;
```

I don't know if the performance will be better.

Comment: Thanks for this solution and it was executing fine except `MIN(MIN(F.FRST_RCVD_DT)) OVER (PARTITION BY F.KEY1, F.KEY3) AS FRST_RCVD_DT` and related ones . Due to which execution time increased more than the original one. Any workaround possible ?

Comment: @ciprian If you are having a performance problem, can you share the SQL Monitor report

Comment: After building indexes on KEY1, KEY2, KEY3,KEY4 performance improved a lot .